# Redirect www and non https to nonwww and https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of different websites on my server and i'm currently using this redirect rule in my htaccess for all of them

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

the htacces files are exactly the same. but for some reason only some of the sites are redirecting www to nonwww and some aren't. Any reason this works for some sites and doesn't work for others?

whats strange is that when i go to www.example.com it doesn't redirect. But when I click on a link on that page such as www.example.com/login. It then redirects the www to https://example.com/login even though the link is www.example.com/login

EDIT: I use the codeigniter framework and have this rule above it to remove the index.php in the url

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: yes, all sites have the exact vhosts setup and i've tried it on different browsers and computers.

Comment: Is there any rule before this rule in your .htaccess?

Comment: yes, i use the codeigniter framework. But it works on my other sites. I added the rule above in the question. But when I comment out those rules it doesn't work either. So I figured that wasn't the issue.

Comment: Keep `301` rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line and completely lear browser cache and then test.

Comment: alright. now it redirects www.example.com to https:// example.com but it doesn't redirect https:// www.example.com to https:// example.com